# Laravel, Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my ProjectController class, I have two methods:

```
private function checkUserProject($project){
    if(!(Auth::check())) return false;
    elseif($project->user_id != Auth::user()->id) return false;
    else return true;
}

public function getProject($project){
    $project = Project::where('unique_id',$project)->first();
    if(!$this->checkUserProject($project)) return Redirect::route('');
    return $this->process($project);
}
```

I get an error of 'trying to get property of non-object' in the `checkUserProject()` method.

I have `return $project` and it returns `$project` completely.

**Edit:**

The error message:

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)  
Trying to get property of non-object

<?php
class Print3dController extends \BaseController
{
private function checkUserProject($project){
    if(!(Auth::check())) return false;
    elseif($project->user_id != Auth::user()->id) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

The output of `dd($project)` is:

```
object(Project)#669 (20) {
    ["table":protected]=>
    string(8) "projects"
    ["connection":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["primaryKey":protected]=>
    string(2) "id"
    ["perPage":protected]=>
    int(15)
    ["incrementing"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["timestamps"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["attributes":protected]=>
    array(14) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(19)
    ["unique_id"]=>
    int(2665861)
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["status_id"]=>
    int(9)
    ["type_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["admin_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["price1"]=>
    NULL
    ["price2"]=>
    NULL
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["response_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["file_has_problem"]=>
    int(0)
    ["problem"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["created_at"]=>
    int(1449402767)
    ["updated_at"]=>
    int(1449991555)
    }
    ["original":protected]=>
    array(14) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(19)
    ["unique_id"]=>
    int(2665861)
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["status_id"]=>
    int(9)
    ["type_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["admin_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["price1"]=>
    NULL
    ["price2"]=>
    NULL
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["response_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["file_has_problem"]=>
    int(0)
    ["problem"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["created_at"]=>
    int(1449402767)
    ["updated_at"]=>
    int(1449991555)
    }
    ["relations":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["hidden":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["visible":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["appends":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["fillable":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["guarded":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "*"
    }
    ["dates":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["touches":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["observables":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["with":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["morphClass":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["exists"]=>
     bool(true)
 }
```

Comment: what is the result of `dd( $project )` if you write it in the first line of `checkUserProject` ?

Comment: its return eloquent model that consist ["user_id"]=> int(1)

Comment: can you edit the post specifying the full error message you get ?

Comment: paste the output of dd( $project )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the case where `$project` may not have the `user_id` variable, so you have to put `empty()` or `isset()` for `$project->user_id` first, then put your Auth check.

Comment: actually its my mistake!